# non standard XML file parse in php

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have problem with phrasing XML file in PHP. Tried diffent approaches, but no luck, can You help with that?
Here is the file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"?>
    <Nadawca Struktura="1.6" Nazwa="Gospodarstwo Szk&#56202;&#56993;rskie Izabela i Ryszard Kie3kowski" NazwaSkrocona="GOSPODARST" Ulica="Kolberga" Dom="84a" Lokal="" Miejscowosc="PSZ&#1175;" Kod="44370" Guid="{08E2DA76-84BF-0406-F455-D83B5DF413D0}" NIP="6422846254" Zrodlo="POCZTA">
      <Zbior Nazwa="2014-03-04\3" DataUtworzenia="2014-03-04T14:18:40" Opis="Pwrd by EN 2014-03-04" IloscPrzesylek="48" Guid="{AF15D898-E79F-A1F8-E47F-820EC461EC2D}">
        <Przesylka Guid="{99FE8373-A250-C22D-F908-FD6D61D9B573}">
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Symbol">832</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="KartaUmowy">xxxx</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Umowa">xxxx</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Uwagi">ccccc </Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="Adresat" Nazwa="Nazwa">xxxx</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="Adresat" Nazwa="Ulica">Okrąg 58 b</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="Adresat" Nazwa="Miejscowosc">LIPNO</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="Adresat" Nazwa="Kod">87600</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="Adresat" Nazwa="Kraj">Polska</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="NrNadania">EE920634112PL</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Ilosc">1</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Masa">1540</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Serwis">E</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Termin">X</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="CzyOplacaOdbiorca">N</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Uslugi">P</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="IloscPotwOdb">0</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="SposobPobrania">S</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="KwotaPobrania">5200</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="Oplata" Nazwa="Razem">0</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Wartosc">0</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="DataNadania">2014-03-04</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="KontaktPowiadomieniaNadawcy">xxxxx</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="FormaPowiadomieniaNadawcy">M</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="FormaPowiadomieniaAdresata">M</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="KontaktPowiadomieniaAdresata">xxxxx</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Wersja">1</Atrybut>
        </Przesylka>
        <Przesylka Guid="{5A705B7E-6F9D-9238-6093-BDB22979A7A4}">
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Symbol">832</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="KartaUmowy">xxxx</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Umowa">xxxx</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Uwagi">xxxxx </Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="Adresat" Nazwa="Nazwa">xxxx</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="Adresat" Nazwa="Ulica">xxxxx</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="Adresat" Nazwa="Miejscowosc">Brzostek</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="Adresat" Nazwa="Kod">39230</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="Adresat" Nazwa="Kraj">Polska</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="NrNadania">EE920634126PL</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Ilosc">1</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Masa">16980</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Serwis">E</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Termin">X</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="CzyOplacaOdbiorca">N</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Uslugi">P</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="IloscPotwOdb">0</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="SposobPobrania">S</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="KwotaPobrania">26400</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="Oplata" Nazwa="Razem">0</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Wartosc">0</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="DataNadania">2014-03-04</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="KontaktPowiadomieniaNadawcy">xxxx</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="FormaPowiadomieniaNadawcy">M</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="FormaPowiadomieniaAdresata">M</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="KontaktPowiadomieniaAdresata">xxxxx</Atrybut>
          <Atrybut Typ="" Nazwa="Wersja">1</Atrybut>
        </Przesylka>
   </Zbior>
</Nadawca>
```

Im trying to cycle through  element to extract data from it for excample

```
I tried this:
$str = file_get_contents('pocztex_import_listow.xml');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
echo 'Displaying user names of XML file...<br />';
foreach($xml as $event_date){
   echo 'Home: '.$event_date->{Nadawca}.'<br />';
}
```

No luck, tryng to use

```
$xml= new SimpleXMLElement('pocztex_import_listow.xml', null, true);
```

but it works the same...I mean it doesn't work :)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific "what doesn't work"? Are you getting any errors? Or is the loop not being run through? Have you tried var_dump()-ing the $xml variable?

Comment: problem is with no output

Answer (score 0):

These Polish characters are invalid for the encoding: `&#56202;&#56993;` found on line:

```
 <Nadawca Struktura="1.6" Nazwa="Gospodarstwo Szk&#56202;&#56993;rskie Iza....
```

Comment: my foult, added closing tags (I cut <Przesylka> entries becouse thera are about 100 of them, all alike so no need to post them all here)